# Recording high-framerate video with libcamera-vid, camera module v3 and rpi 3B

Tags: camera, raspicam, libcamera

**UPDATE**: According to [this issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/503), it seems that 120fps with the camera module v3 is only possible with a RPI 4, so this kind of answer my question.
I'm not sure how to handle this case (self-answering a question) and I'm leaving the question open for now.

### Original Question

I'm trying to record a high-framerate video using a **RPI 3B** running **raspbian 11**, a camera module **v3** and **libcamera-vid** (v0.0.4+22-923f5d70).

I have followed the instructions regarding high-framerate in the official libcamera documentation :

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#high-framerate-capture

So far, this is the command-line I've devised should do what I want :

```
libcamera-vid -n --level 4.2 --framerate 120 --width 640 --height 480 -o /dev/shm/tst.h264 --save-pts /dev/shm/timestamp.pts --denoise cdn_off -t 4000
```

It is my understanding that recording a 120fps video for 4 seconds should provide me with a 480 frame long video, and yet, the resulting video file has only 274 frames*, which only amounts to 68.5fps.

**This is reflected by the generated pts file, which has only 274 entries, and match the result given by the above command when using `-v 2` for a more verbose output;*

> Closing Libcamera application(frames displayed 274, dropped 0

I've found several discussions on raspbberypi.com forums concerning achieving high framerate on the v2 camera, and have tried the various commands found in these but to no avail ;

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=345883

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=345520

FWIW, using the old camera stack, raspivid and a v1 camera module works for a 640x480@90fps on this very same system.

Has anyone had success recording 640x480 or more, 90fps or more, video with the **same setup** ? If so, could you share your complete workflow ?

Thanks!